# Simple way to use the google contacts API from a python script

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm currently trying to write a script and I would need to access my GMail contacts to finish it. I tried googling that a bit and it looks like there are a few libraries to do that, but some answers seems very old, and some others aren't that clear.

What is the correct way currently to access the contacts API from a script ? Using https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client I assume ?

Any recent response seems to involve the user copying a link into his browser by hand, getting redirected to some non-existent URL and being asked to copy that URL back in the script to parse the code in it. That seems perfectly ridiculous, I do hope there is a proper way to access the API for non-web applications ?

I'll be the only user of that script so I don't mind having to put my full e-mail address and password in if that makes it easier, as long as I don't have to keep re-authenticating by hand. Just want to authorize it once and have it work forever. I'm just trying to find the contact's name from the phone number so I don't even need to access everything.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

Comment: Yes, but that does seem to involve the redirection nonsense, copying links by hand in and out of the browser. I guess if it's only once it's fine, but I understand the tokens are short time ?

Comment: Did you read the OAuth 2.0 section on the page I linked to? The tokens are indeed short-lived, but you acquire a new one each time the user authorises your application (#5: `Google displays an OAuth dialog to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.`). So no manual copy-pasting required AFAIK, unless you're referring to the the client ID and secret, but those do not expire at all (I believe).

Comment: Yeah that's what I saw, and for me a "dialog to the user" means copy pasting. I don't see how Google can display anything outside of a browser, and as I mentioned I'm doing a script, it won't be running on a desktop, it's headless. Copying the links would be okay if the tokens weren't short lived, but I can't be doing that every day, that's just unusable. I assume there must be some other way to access the data, my phone for example isn't asking me every time to authorize the contact app over and over again. Now maybe that API isn't public, that'd be disappointing. Guess I'll just drop it

Comment: Well, I've yet to try out the Contacts API but perhaps you'll be able to perform the copy-pasting programmatically?

Comment: You might also want to check out this page (it mentions refresh tokens): https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: Well no, since the script won't be running on a desktop, there is nowhere to copy it to. But yeah I was just told of the refresh tokens, that's what I was missing ! Thanks, looks like what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I'm using in the end :

```
if arg == "--init":
    gflow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='<ID>', client_secret='<secret>',
                            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
                            redirect_uri='http://localhost');
    gflow.params['access_type'] = 'offline';
    auth_uri = gflow.step1_get_authorize_url();
    weechat.prnt("", "Please go to " + auth_uri + " and come back here with the code. Run /gauth code");
else:
    credentials = gflow.step2_exchange(arg);
    storage.put(credentials);
    http = httplib2.Http();
    http = credentials.authorize(http);
    people = build('people', 'v1', http=http);
```

Works fine with that. I do need to copy / paste the URL by hand and then get the code out of the redirection, but since I put the access_type to offline I have to do that only once.